# Obtener un valor en lugar de un objeto en un SELECT en Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-directivas

Tengo el siguiente código que me muestra una serie de horas desde las 07 hasta las 22. Lo que quiero saber es como obtener el valor de la hora seleccionada en mi controller y si es posible imprimir en un alert.

Vista html

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="item item-divider item-positive item-text-wrap">
          HORA INGRESO
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col .col-50">
            <div class="item item-input item-select">
              <div class="input-label">HH</div>
              <select ng-model="data.hih" ng-init="data.hih=horas[0]" ng-options="hih.hora for hih in horas">
              </select>
            </div>          
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="button button-block icon-left ion-ios-compose button-balanced" 

          ng-click="crearTutoria()">
          Crear Tutoría
        </a>
</div>
```

Controlador

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.horas = [];
    for(var i=7;i<=22;i++){
      if(i<10){
        $scope.iconcatenado='0'+i;
        $scope.horas.push({hora:$scope.iconcatenado});
      }else{
        $scope.horas.push({hora:i});
      }
    }

    $scope.data = {};
    //9.1 hace referencia al data de CrearTutoria.html
    $scope.crearTutoria=function(){
        alert($scope.data.hih)//esto me muestra [Object:Object]
        alert(JSON.stringify($scope.data.hih))// me imprime hora:07 y lo que solo quiero obtener es 07 o el cualquier valor seleccionado
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que cambiar la expresión de tu [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) de esto

```
ng-options="hih.hora for hih in horas"
```

a esto

```
ng-options="hih.hora as hih.hora for hih in horas"
```

Esto puede ser un poco confuso de entender así que te lo explico por partes.

Estoy usando la sintáxis `select as label for value in array` en lugar de `label for value in array` porque de acuerdo a la documentación

> Cuando una opción en el `<select>` es seleccionada, el elemento del arreglo o propiedad del objeto representado por la opción seleccionada será asignada al modelo identificado por la directiva ngModel.

La traducción de esto es que `ng-options` **siempre** te seleccionará el objeto indicado (tu tienes un arreglo de **objetos**) a menos que se le especifique lo contrario.

Ahí es cuando entra en juego la otra sintáxis. Las diferentes partes de `select as label for value in array` significan

- `select`: Es la expresión que se evaluará y será asignada a ng-model cuando una opción sea seleccionada (equivalente al atributo `value` del elemento `<option>`, para este tipo de expresiones se asigna el índice del arreglo).
- `label`: Es una expresión que será evaluada y mostrada en cada uno de los `<option>` cuando expandes el `select` (el contenido de texto dentro del elemento `option`)
- `value`: Una variable que representa cada elemento de la colección
- `array`: La colección en la que estás iterando

La expresión que te puse `hih.hora as hih.hora for hih in horas` significa en resumidas cuentas

> Asigna la propiedad `hora` del objeto seleccionado dentro del arreglo en $scope.horas al ng-model y crea una lista de opciones a partir de este arreglo con el texto igual al valor de la propiedad `hora`

Me parece que de esta forma es más fácil entenderlo. Aquí te dejo un demo funcionando

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.horas = [];
  for (var i = 7; i <= 22; i++) {
    if (i < 10) {
      $scope.iconcatenado = '0' + i;
      $scope.horas.push({
        hora: $scope.iconcatenado
      });
    } else {
      $scope.horas.push({
        hora: i
      });
    }
  }

  $scope.data = {
     // El valor inicial se cambia actualizando el valor de ngModel
     hih: $scope.horas[0].hora
  };
  //9.1 hace referencia al data de CrearTutoria.html
  $scope.crearTutoria = function() {
    alert($scope.data.hih) //esto me muestra [Object:Object]
    alert(JSON.stringify($scope.data.hih)) // me imprime hora:07 y lo que solo quiero obtener es 07 o el cualquier valor seleccionado
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="item item-divider item-positive item-text-wrap">
      HORA INGRESO
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col .col-50">
        <div class="item item-input item-select">
          <div class="input-label">HH</div>
          <select ng-model="data.hih" ng-options="hih.hora as hih.hora for hih in horas">
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="button button-block icon-left ion-ios-compose button-balanced" ng-click="crearTutoria()">
          Crear Tutoría
        </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias siempre por sus respuestas son muy buenas, pero como haria para que me muestre el valor 07 por defecto en el SELECT porque en su ejemplo aparece en blanco

Comment: @DiegoIsraelMoreno Ya actualizé el ejemplo. En todos los casos eso se logra actualizando el valor asociado al `ng-model`. Esto se puede hacer tanto en un `ng-init` como en un controller. Yo lo hice usando la segunda variante ya que en muy raras ocasiones usar `ng-init` es recomendado. Anteriormente fallaba porque estaba asignandole un objeto `horas[0]` en lugar de un valor `horas[0].hora`. De la otra forma sería `ng-init="data.hih=horas[0].hora"`. Recuerda que ahora en el `ng-model` lo que hay son valores primitivos y no objetos.

Comment: Gracias por siempre ayudarme es una Excelente Respuesta.